# need to create ajax call with abort and time interval

Tags: ajax

I have one SELECT element with a js function refreshme() which will call on change event.

```
<select id="cat" name="cat" multiple  onchange="refreshme()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>


<script>
function refreshme()
{
     /* i need output in $('#result').html(data) */
}
</script>
```

Here i want to call a URL "demo.php" using ajax when we change select/Unselect listbox item.  Problem is that  when user select item then it calls ajax function immediaterly. I want to set some intermal so that if user select one by one listbox then ajax does not call. I want to setup approx 2 seconds gap. That means ajax call should be call after 2 seconds of last selected item. If user select any other listbox then ajax call be abort if it is running and waiting for result.

Comment: var ajaxcall = $.ajax() ;             ajaxcall.abort(); its only destroy client side request not on server side

Comment: or you need confirmation from user before ajax calling  mean .use prompt function and confirm it and call the ajax

Answer (score 1):

following method is only destroy the client side request not on sever side .may be it will help you

```
<script>

function refreshme()
{
    if(ajaxcall)
     {

       ajaxcall.abort();  //abort the previous request 
     }

    var ajaxcall = $.ajax() ;  //ajax request start here assign to variable 

    //here you can also use array and destroy it using for loop    
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer myself with ajax and timer as under. Perhaps this may help to others.

```
<select id="cat" name="cat" multiple  onchange="refreshme()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>


<script>

var timer;
var x;

function refreshme()
{
    $('#result').html('');

    if (x) { x.abort() } // XHR  abort 
    clearTimeout(timer); // Clear the timer  
    timer = setTimeout(function() {  
        x = $.post('demo.php',function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
            }); // run ajax request and store in x variable  
    }, 2000); // 2000ms delay 

}
</script>
```